# Why the GitLab CI/CD fail with multistage Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

Following [this Spring Blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/27/creating-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3-0-m1) I have a multistage Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=./hello/build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract
ADD ./dependencies/ ./


FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
# COPY --from=builder application/resources/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

It works perfectly in a local environment with: `docker build . --tag hello`.

I want to run a GitLab CI/CD pipeline that builds this Dockerfile, so my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```yaml
image: openjdk:11

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

stages:
  - build
  - release

build hello:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ./hello
    - ./gradlew build -x test --stacktrace
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./hello/build/libs/*.jar
  only:
    changes:
      - hello/**/*

release hello:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/myproject/hello --file ./Dockerfile .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/myproject/hello
  only:
    changes:
      - hello/**/*
```

but... it fail because between the two stages of the Dockerfile the extracted (from the builder) folders can't be found.

How can I solve this and implement a working GitLab CI/CD that build the image from that Dockerfile?

---

**EDIT:**

If I add a `RUN ls application` command, after every `COPY` command, in the second phase:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot AS builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=./hello/build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract


FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies ./
RUN ls application
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies ./
RUN ls application
# COPY --from=builder application/resources ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader ./
RUN ls application
COPY --from=builder application/application ./
RUN ls application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

The GitLab CI/CD works correctly. Isn't this weird?

Comment: at first sight it could just be an absolute/relative path issue. Maybe try replacing `WORKDIR application` with `WORKDIR /app` and `COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./` with `COPY --from=builder /app/dependencies/ ./` (so, with a leading slash)?

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. The problem seems to be that between the first Dockerfile phase and the second (in the stage `release` of the GitLab CI/CD), there are no extracted folders. As if the second phase of the Dockerfile was running in a clean environment.